# Converting a splitted objects of object to array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reduce

I have this form of data coming from an API and I want it to convert into different structure in JavaScript .

```
[
  {
    "1": {
      "id": 1,
      "coinname": "Binance Coin",
      "symbol": "BNB",
      "owner": "NULL",
      "repo": "NULL",
      "language": "NULL",
      "total_public_repos": 0,
      "tosymbol": "BUSD",
      "exchanges": "Binance",
      "coinlimit": "-1",
      "category": "coin",
      "domain": "cryptocurrency",
      "country": "china",
      "logo": "",
      "flag": "",
      "Product_Live": null,
      "Funds_Raised": null,
      "Sale_type": "BFT",
      "Whitepaper": "",
      "website": "https://www.binance.com/",
      "type": "blockchain",
      "launched": null,
      "Algo_used": "n/a",
      "ExchangesCount": 25,
      "platform": "bsc"
    },
    "2": {
      "id": 2,
      "coinname": "Bitcoin",
      "symbol": "BTC",
      "owner": "Bitcoin",
      "repo": "bitcoin",
      "language": "C++",
      "total_public_repos": 4,
      "tosymbol": "USD",
      "exchanges": "Coinbase",
      "coinlimit": "20,999,999.98",
      "category": "Currency",
      "domain": "cryptocurrency",
      "country": "japan",
      "logo": "",
      "flag": "",
      "Product_Live": null,
      "Funds_Raised": null,
      "Sale_type": "PoW",
      "Whitepaper": "https://www.cryptocompare.com/media/37745820/bitcoin.pdf",
      "website": "https://bitcoin.org/en/",
      "type": "blockchain",
      "launched": null,
      "Algo_used": "SHA-256",
      "ExchangesCount": 72,
      "platform": null
    }
  },
  {
    "1": {
      "id": 1,
      "price": 400.6,
      "marketcap": 67355696581.54001,
      "timestamp": 1651737822,
      "datetime": "2022-05-05 08:03:42"
    },
    "2": {
      "id": 2,
      "price": 39538.5,
      "marketcap": 752463351490.5,
      "timestamp": 1651737817,
      "datetime": "2022-05-05 08:03:37"
    }
  },
  {
    "1": {
      "id": 1,
      "last30dcommits": null,
      "activity": "No Github Repo Found"
    },
    "2": {
      "id": 2,
      "last30dcommits": 154,
      "activity": "High Activity"
    }
  },
  {
    "1": {
      "id": 1,
      "change24h": 2.87,
      "change7d": 2.12,
      "change30d": -13.41,
      "timestamp24h": 1651651200,
      "timestamp7d": 1651132800,
      "timestamp30d": 1649145600
    },
    "2": {
      "id": 2,
      "change24h": 2.26,
      "change7d": 0.47,
      "change30d": -18.04,
      "timestamp24h": 1651651200,
      "timestamp7d": 1651132800,
      "timestamp30d": 1649145600
    }
  },
  {
    "1": {
      "tweetsRating": 14.36,
      "newsRating": 34.4
    },
    "2": {
      "tweetsRating": 16.41,
      "newsRating": 43.44
    }
  },
  {
    "1": {
      "score": 70
    },
    "2": {
      "score": 93.33
    }
  }
]
```

this is the data I am receiving . Now I want a data like this

```
[
   {
      "id": 1,
      "coinname": "Binance Coin",
      "symbol": "BNB",
      "owner": "NULL",
      "repo": "NULL",
      "language": "NULL",
      "total_public_repos": 0,
      "tosymbol": "BUSD",
      "exchanges": "Binance",
      "coinlimit": "-1",
      "category": "coin",
      "domain": "cryptocurrency",
      "country": "china",
      "logo": "",
      "flag": "",
      "Product_Live": null,
      "Funds_Raised": null,
      "Sale_type": "BFT",
      "Whitepaper": "",
      "website": "https://www.binance.com/",
      "type": "blockchain",
      "launched": null,
      "Algo_used": "n/a",
      "ExchangesCount": 25,
      "platform": "bsc",
      "price": 400.6,
      "marketcap": 67355696581.54001,
      "timestamp": 1651737822,
      "datetime": "2022-05-05 08:03:42",
      "last30dcommits": null,
      "activity": "No Github Repo Found",
      "change24h": 2.87,
      "change7d": 2.12,
      "change30d": -13.41,
      "timestamp24h": 1651651200,
      "timestamp7d": 1651132800,
      "timestamp30d": 1649145600,
    "tweetsRating": 14.36,
      "newsRating": 34.4,
    "score": 70
    },
     {
      "id": 2,
      "coinname": "Bitcoin",
      "symbol": "BTC",
      "owner": "Bitcoin",
      "repo": "bitcoin",
      "language": "C++",
      "total_public_repos": 4,
      "tosymbol": "USD",
      "exchanges": "Coinbase",
      "coinlimit": "20,999,999.98",
      "category": "Currency",
      "domain": "cryptocurrency",
      "country": "japan",
      "logo": "",
      "flag": "",
      "Product_Live": null,
      "Funds_Raised": null,
      "Sale_type": "PoW",
      "Whitepaper": "https://www.cryptocompare.com/media/37745820/bitcoin.pdf",
      "website": "https://bitcoin.org/en/",
      "type": "blockchain",
      "launched": null,
      "Algo_used": "SHA-256",
      "ExchangesCount": 72,
      "platform": null,
    "price": 400.6,
      "marketcap": 67355696581.54001,
      "timestamp": 1651737822,
      "datetime": "2022-05-05 08:03:42",
      "last30dcommits": null,
      "activity": "No Github Repo Found",
      "change24h": 2.87,
      "change7d": 2.12,
      "change30d": -13.41,
      "timestamp24h": 1651651200,
      "timestamp7d": 1651132800,
      "timestamp30d": 1649145600,
      "tweetsRating": 14.36,
      "newsRating": 34.4,
    "score": 70
    }
   
]
```

For clarification . The 1 , 2 3,...etc are the coin id of each coin and the data coming in previous code is coming from 6 sources . hence its coming as object of objects and that too separately . Now I want it this way where for each coin all the data is segregated to one single object .
Hope I am clear in terms of the problem . Any help would be highly appreciable.

Comment: Try this one , `const newArr = arr.reduce((acc, c) => {
  const keys = Object.keys(c);
  for (i of keys) acc.push(c[i]);
  return acc;
}, []);
`

Comment: Its not adding properties for the same coin from other objects together . Few changes is required in this code. BTW thanks for the help .

Answer (score 1):

This code I think that it works like you want.

```
const dataIN = [
  {
    "1": {
      "id": 1,
      "coinname": "Binance Coin",
      "symbol": "BNB",
      "owner": "NULL",
      "repo": "NULL",
      "language": "NULL",
      "total_public_repos": 0,
      "tosymbol": "BUSD",
      "exchanges": "Binance",
      "coinlimit": "-1",
      "category": "coin",
      "domain": "cryptocurrency",
      "country": "china",
      "logo": "",
      "flag": "",
      "Product_Live": null,
      "Funds_Raised": null,
      "Sale_type": "BFT",
      "Whitepaper": "",
      "website": "https://www.binance.com/",
      "type": "blockchain",
      "launched": null,
      "Algo_used": "n/a",
      "ExchangesCount": 25,
      "platform": "bsc"
    },
    "2": {
      "id": 2,
      "coinname": "Bitcoin",
      "symbol": "BTC",
      "owner": "Bitcoin",
      "repo": "bitcoin",
      "language": "C++",
      "total_public_repos": 4,
      "tosymbol": "USD",
      "exchanges": "Coinbase",
      "coinlimit": "20,999,999.98",
      "category": "Currency",
      "domain": "cryptocurrency",
      "country": "japan",
      "logo": "",
      "flag": "",
      "Product_Live": null,
      "Funds_Raised": null,
      "Sale_type": "PoW",
      "Whitepaper": "https://www.cryptocompare.com/media/37745820/bitcoin.pdf",
      "website": "https://bitcoin.org/en/",
      "type": "blockchain",
      "launched": null,
      "Algo_used": "SHA-256",
      "ExchangesCount": 72,
      "platform": null
    }
  },
  {
    "1": {
      "id": 1,
      "price": 400.6,
      "marketcap": 67355696581.54001,
      "timestamp": 1651737822,
      "datetime": "2022-05-05 08:03:42"
    },
    "2": {
      "id": 2,
      "price": 39538.5,
      "marketcap": 752463351490.5,
      "timestamp": 1651737817,
      "datetime": "2022-05-05 08:03:37"
    }
  },
  {
    "1": {
      "id": 1,
      "last30dcommits": null,
      "activity": "No Github Repo Found"
    },
    "2": {
      "id": 2,
      "last30dcommits": 154,
      "activity": "High Activity"
    }
  },
  {
    "1": {
      "id": 1,
      "change24h": 2.87,
      "change7d": 2.12,
      "change30d": -13.41,
      "timestamp24h": 1651651200,
      "timestamp7d": 1651132800,
      "timestamp30d": 1649145600
    },
    "2": {
      "id": 2,
      "change24h": 2.26,
      "change7d": 0.47,
      "change30d": -18.04,
      "timestamp24h": 1651651200,
      "timestamp7d": 1651132800,
      "timestamp30d": 1649145600
    }
  },
  {
    "1": {
      "tweetsRating": 14.36,
      "newsRating": 34.4
    },
    "2": {
      "tweetsRating": 16.41,
      "newsRating": 43.44
    }
  },
  {
    "1": {
      "score": 70
    },
    "2": {
      "score": 93.33
    }
  }
];

function Question21() {
  const positionsId = {};
  const dataOUT = [];
  dataIN.forEach((element) => {
    const ids = Object.keys(element);
    ids.forEach((idKey) => {
      const objectInfo = element[idKey];
      const posDataOUT = positionsId[idKey];
      if (posDataOUT === undefined) {
        positionsId[idKey] = dataOUT.length;
        dataOUT.push(objectInfo);
      } else {
        dataOUT[posDataOUT] = { ...dataOUT[posDataOUT], ...objectInfo };
      }
    });
  });
  console.log(dataOUT);

  return (
    <div>Question 21 - check console</div>
  );
}

export default Question21;
```

Comment: Thanks a lott man . You're a saviour.. It worked .

Answer (score 0):

This should also work:

```js
const data=[{"1": {"id": 1, "coinname": "Binance Coin", "symbol": "BNB", "owner": "NULL", "repo": "NULL", "language": "NULL", "total_public_repos": 0, "tosymbol": "BUSD", "exchanges": "Binance", "coinlimit": "-1", "category": "coin", "domain": "cryptocurrency", "country": "china", "logo": "", "flag": "", "Product_Live": null, "Funds_Raised": null, "Sale_type": "BFT", "Whitepaper": "", "website": "https://www.binance.com/", "type": "blockchain", "launched": null, "Algo_used": "n/a", "ExchangesCount": 25, "platform": "bsc"} , "2": {"id": 2, "coinname": "Bitcoin", "symbol": "BTC", "owner": "Bitcoin", "repo": "bitcoin", "language": "C++", "total_public_repos": 4, "tosymbol": "USD", "exchanges": "Coinbase", "coinlimit": "20,999,999.98", "category": "Currency", "domain": "cryptocurrency", "country": "japan", "logo": "", "flag": "", "Product_Live": null, "Funds_Raised": null, "Sale_type": "PoW", "Whitepaper": "https://www.cryptocompare.com/media/37745820/bitcoin.pdf", "website": "https://bitcoin.org/en/", "type": "blockchain", "launched": null, "Algo_used": "SHA-256", "ExchangesCount": 72, "platform": null} } , {"1": {"id": 1, "price": 400.6, "marketcap": 67355696581.54001, "timestamp": 1651737822, "datetime": "2022-05-05 08:03:42"} , "2": {"id": 2, "price": 39538.5, "marketcap": 752463351490.5, "timestamp": 1651737817, "datetime": "2022-05-05 08:03:37"} } , {"1": {"id": 1, "last30dcommits": null, "activity": "No Github Repo Found"} , "2": {"id": 2, "last30dcommits": 154, "activity": "High Activity"} } , {"1": {"id": 1, "change24h": 2.87, "change7d": 2.12, "change30d": -13.41, "timestamp24h": 1651651200, "timestamp7d": 1651132800, "timestamp30d": 1649145600} , "2": {"id": 2, "change24h": 2.26, "change7d": 0.47, "change30d": -18.04, "timestamp24h": 1651651200, "timestamp7d": 1651132800, "timestamp30d": 1649145600} } , {"1": {"tweetsRating": 14.36, "newsRating": 34.4} , "2": {"tweetsRating": 16.41, "newsRating": 43.44} } , {"1": {"score": 70} , "2": {"score": 93.33} }];
const res={};
data.forEach(c=>
 Object.entries(c).forEach(([id,ob])=>{
  let curr=(res[id]=res[id]||{});
  Object.entries(ob).forEach(([k,v])=>res[id][k]=v)
 })
)
console.log(res)
```

There are two nested loops:

- the outer one over all `id`s
- and the inner one over all properties of the objects found in the outer loop

Answer (score 0):

```js
// we'll call this below at end, hoisting here for visibility
function processAPI(obj) {
  var table = {};
  var final = [];
  for (var prop in obj) {
    var item = obj[prop];
    var group = table[prop];
    if (!group) {
      group = table[prop] = {};
      final.push(group);
    }
    for (var key in item) {
      group[key] = item[key];
    }
  }
  return final;
}

var apiFeed = [{
    "1": {
      "id": 1,
      "coinname": "Binance Coin",
      "symbol": "BNB",
      "owner": "NULL",
      "repo": "NULL",
      "language": "NULL",
      "total_public_repos": 0,
      "tosymbol": "BUSD",
      "exchanges": "Binance",
      "coinlimit": "-1",
      "category": "coin",
      "domain": "cryptocurrency",
      "country": "china",
      "logo": "",
      "flag": "",
      "Product_Live": null,
      "Funds_Raised": null,
      "Sale_type": "BFT",
      "Whitepaper": "",
      "website": "https://www.binance.com/",
      "type": "blockchain",
      "launched": null,
      "Algo_used": "n/a",
      "ExchangesCount": 25,
      "platform": "bsc"
    },
    "2": {
      "id": 2,
      "coinname": "Bitcoin",
      "symbol": "BTC",
      "owner": "Bitcoin",
      "repo": "bitcoin",
      "language": "C++",
      "total_public_repos": 4,
      "tosymbol": "USD",
      "exchanges": "Coinbase",
      "coinlimit": "20,999,999.98",
      "category": "Currency",
      "domain": "cryptocurrency",
      "country": "japan",
      "logo": "",
      "flag": "",
      "Product_Live": null,
      "Funds_Raised": null,
      "Sale_type": "PoW",
      "Whitepaper": "https://www.cryptocompare.com/media/37745820/bitcoin.pdf",
      "website": "https://bitcoin.org/en/",
      "type": "blockchain",
      "launched": null,
      "Algo_used": "SHA-256",
      "ExchangesCount": 72,
      "platform": null
    }
  },
  {
    "1": {
      "id": 1,
      "price": 400.6,
      "marketcap": 67355696581.54001,
      "timestamp": 1651737822,
      "datetime": "2022-05-05 08:03:42"
    },
    "2": {
      "id": 2,
      "price": 39538.5,
      "marketcap": 752463351490.5,
      "timestamp": 1651737817,
      "datetime": "2022-05-05 08:03:37"
    }
  },
  {
    "1": {
      "id": 1,
      "last30dcommits": null,
      "activity": "No Github Repo Found"
    },
    "2": {
      "id": 2,
      "last30dcommits": 154,
      "activity": "High Activity"
    }
  },
  {
    "1": {
      "id": 1,
      "change24h": 2.87,
      "change7d": 2.12,
      "change30d": -13.41,
      "timestamp24h": 1651651200,
      "timestamp7d": 1651132800,
      "timestamp30d": 1649145600
    },
    "2": {
      "id": 2,
      "change24h": 2.26,
      "change7d": 0.47,
      "change30d": -18.04,
      "timestamp24h": 1651651200,
      "timestamp7d": 1651132800,
      "timestamp30d": 1649145600
    }
  },
  {
    "1": {
      "tweetsRating": 14.36,
      "newsRating": 34.4
    },
    "2": {
      "tweetsRating": 16.41,
      "newsRating": 43.44
    }
  },
  {
    "1": {
      "score": 70
    },
    "2": {
      "score": 93.33
    }
  }
]

// process the 1st item in the provided list... in theory, they may provide multiple items to you... here we're only doing one
var data = processAPI(apiFeed[0]);

console.log("data", data);
```